# Android beginner issue

Tags: android

This is my first time working with the Android framework. I followed the guidelines on the Android page to make a test app. Even after doing exactly how they mention, I get errors like this (for clarity sake, I only mentioned few of them). I really can't figure out how to go from here.

> [2013-06-21 08:46:37 - My First App] W/ResourceType( 7940): Bad XML block: header size 122 or total size 8002512 is larger than data size 0
>   [2013-06-21 08:46:37 - My First App] C:\Users\llp-admin\workspace3\My First App\res\layout\activity_main.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').

This is the activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name ="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name = "action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name = "title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: your xml is wrong. Beginner answer...

Comment: post you whole layout.xml file instead

Comment: there is no string `edit_message` in your `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

make a string called edit_message

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using an undefined string reference, add the following to the strings.xml

```
<string name = "edit_message">Editing</string>
```

The value you use for your edittext's hint - `@string/edit_message` is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

The error right here

```
(at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').
```

is wanting something along the lines of

```
<string name = "edit_message">This is the hint</string>
```

added to the .xml file.

Answer (score 1):

add in string.xml

```
 <string name = "edit_message">This is edit text</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is at `android:hint`. you are specifying the code to go to string.xml and use the entry with the name edit_message as the hint for your Edit text box. But there is no entry called edit_message in string.xml. 
    So add,

```
<string name = "edit_message">This is the hint</string>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should define each and every String to which you give the reference in your xml file. Here, in your case you have given reference to a String called edit_message.

You must be knowing that @+id stands for adding your resource to the R.java file.

So you should either hardcode the string

```
    android:hint="This is my hardcoded string"
```

or you can keep reference like you have kept and define the string in strings.xml file in package explorer-->your project-->res-->values-->strings.xml file like this

```
    <string name = "edit_message">message You want to show</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<string name="et_message"">Your String Here</string>
```

in your Strings.xml file

Comment: I removed the link to your blog, which is unrelated to the question. Excessive promotion of a specific product/resource may be perceived by the community as **spam**. Take a look at the [help], specially [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)'s last section: _Avoid overt self-promotion_. You might also be interested in [How do I advertise on Stack Overflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).